# new to Xpath expression

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

ty in advance for the help
I'm no guru, and I'm sure what I need is fairly simple
Hopefully someone can help me with this

Here's the HTML code example
`<title>Mathew - Public Profile</title>`

I've been able to get the `<title>` in my google spreadsheet using =IMPORTXML("URL", "//title"). However it returns me this:

```
Mathew - Public Profile
```

I would want the expression to only return:
Mathew

The profile name will always change and that is what I want to capture
The part where it shows " - Public Profile" I do not want nor need

Is there anyway I can have it removed directly from the XPath expression?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The XPath expression `substring-before(//title, ' - Public Profile')` will give you what you are asking for. However, note that your previous expression returned a node, whereas this returns a string, so at the application level where you are invoking the expression, the handling of the result may be slightly different depending on the API that you are using. I'm not familiar with the google spreadsheet API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXEXTRACT` like this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392296/new-to-xpath-expression"; "//title"); "^(.+?)\s*-[^-]+$" )
```

**UPDATE**
Note that `REGEXEXTRACT` and `IMPORTXML` are not part of XPath, they are part of Google Spreadsheets

Comment: Note that REGEXEXTRACT and IMPORTXML are not part of XPath, they are part of some framework that you may or may not be using to invoke XPath.

Comment: @MichaelKayUpdated my answer. I do not know why, but I thought that `substring-before` is a part of XPath 2 that is not supported by Google Spreadsheets. Thank you for your answer!